# Cannot override a magento Block in magento 1.8

Tags: php, xml, magento, overriding, block

I'm overriding this Block: `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Create_Form_Address`. But it cannot make it work, I'm stuck. Please see as below my code.

My config.xml in app/code/community/Urmagento/Orderaddress/etc/config.xml:

```
<config>
<modules>
    <Urmagento_Orderaddress>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Urmagento_Orderaddress>
</modules>
<global>
    <models>
        <orderaddress>
            <class>Urmagento_Orderaddress_Model</class>
        </orderaddress>
    </models>
    <helpers>
        <orderaddress>
            <class>Urmagento_Orderaddress_Helper</class>
        </orderaddress>
    </helpers>
    <resources>
        <orderaddress_setup>
            <setup>
                <module>Urmagento_Orderaddress</module>
            </setup>
        </orderaddress_setup>
    </resources>
    <blocks>
        <adminhtml>
            <rewrite>
                <sales_order_create_form_address>Urmagento_Orderaddress_Block_Adminhtml_Form_Address</sales_order_create_form_address>
            </rewrite>
        </adminhtml>
    </blocks>
</global>
```

My Urmagento_Orderaddress.xml in app/etc/modules:

```
<config>
<modules>
    <Urmagento_Orderaddress>
        <active>true</active>
        <codePool>community</codePool>
    </Urmagento_Orderaddress>
</modules>
```

My Address.php in app/code/community/Urmagento/Orderaddress/Block/Adminhtml/Form:

```
class Urmagento_Orderaddress_Block_Adminhtml_Form_Address extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Create_Form_Address{ }
```

Can anybody help me ????

Comment: what issue you face ?

Comment: I need to add some code in this core block Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Create_Form_Address, but it not work when I override it ???. But I try to modify inside this block in magento core, my code work well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your not creating block folder as you add  your path

```
app/code/community/Urmagento/Orderaddress/Adminhtml/Form:
```

it should be

```
app/code/community/Urmagento/Orderaddress/Block/Adminhtml/Form
```

**EDIT**

Or see this http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/223637/

hope this will help you